# React Native Firebase phone auth is not working for ios

Tags: firebase, react-native, one-time-password

I want make signin with phone validation,I am followed document steps , android is work but when I try ios device ,app be crash, please help me!!!

Comment: The Apple Phone API only works on a real device. You can only test on real devices if you have a paid Apple Developer account.

Comment: i tested the app on real device but the result did not change

Comment: To receive a timely and relevant response to your problem, you'll need to add more detail like code involved in the execution, relevant sections of the crash log (not the whole log), context, etc. Simply saying "it crashed" is not enough to receive help.

Comment: I get this message ,*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'